# removing items from a dojo datagrid

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo

I am struggling with a simple dojo datagrid in my Zend Framework project.

I have a list of data from a mysql table that I can display, however I want users to be able to remove selected rows (and remove them from the db). I am using the example from [Dojo DataGrid adding and deleting data](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid#adding-and-deleting-data). My code in my view for the datagrid looks like this.

```
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="skillstore" url="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/skills/hist/<?php echo $this->histid;?>"></div>

<table id="skillgrid" jsId="skills" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="skillstore"   style="height:300px;width:500px;">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th field="skillid" hidden="true"></th>
        <th width="auto" field="skill">Skills</th>
    </tr>
        
</thead>
</table>
<div>
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onclick="removeRows()" >Remove Selected Row</button>
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onclick="addRow()">Add another skill</button>
</div>
```

I've placed the code for the removing of the rows inbetween the view scripts captureStart and captureEnd tags.  The code for the removeRows() looks like this.

```
function removeRows(e){     
    var items = skillsgrid.selection.getSelected();
    
    if(items.length){
    
        dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem){
        
            if(selectedItem !== null){
                            
                skillstore.deleteItem(selectedItem);
            }//endif
        });//end foreach
    
    }//end if
}
```

The main problem I get is that when I select a row and click the button, firebugs complains that skillstore.deleteItem is not a function.  I have yet to try and remove the entry from the database.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is `skillstore`? I see that it is the `store` attribute of the table. I don't know Dojo very well - does that mean it is initialized automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you have to do is use the `jsId` attribute value as ID instead of the `id` one:

```
var items = skills.selection.getSelected();
```

**EDIT**:

If that doesn't work, did you add the following right after the closing `body` tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
</script>
```

**EDIT2**:

Actually, you are using a read-only store, that is the problem.

Comment: sadly I still get the same error about selectedItem.deleteItem is not a function??

Comment: Thanks for this however I now have a different error message now of dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore: invalid item argument, in the dojo.js file.  I've checked my code to ensure that the all references for the grid is using the ItemFileWriteStore. Any Ideas?

Comment: Does this help (especially the first answer)? http://www.dojotoolkit.org/forum/dojox-dojox/dojox-grid-support/dojo-data-itemfilereadstore-invalid-item-argument-when-deleting

Comment: @Franz The link that you provided is down. Please give some other Link.

Comment: Maybe this one: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/get-error-quot-dojo-data-ItemFileReadStore-Invalid-item-argument-quot-when-I-call-deleteItem-td425546.html#none

Answer (score 1):

These would I do.

declaring dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore"); is a must. That's why firebugs complains that skillstore.deleteItem is not a function' because there is no 'deleteItem' in ItemFileReadStore but is found in 'ItemFileWriteStore'.

```
function removeRows(e){         
        var items = skillsgrid.selection.getSelected();
        if(items.length){
                dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem){
                      skillsgrid.store.deleteItem(selectedItem); 
                      skillsgrid.sort(); // I did access the store of the grid directly.
                });//end foreach

        }//end if
}
```